# How to complete a "Defend [Settlement]" quest if no one's there?

Tags: fallout-4

Listed in my quests, under 'miscellaneous', is *Defend Graygarden*. I fast traveled there to find only one bad guy present and they were quickly dispatched, but the quest didn't update or become complete.

I'm playing on PC so all console options are available to me. Attempted, but with no success, I tried `disable/enable` on the one corpse, `resurrect` no less than ten times, and `killall` - nojoy. The first time this happened, I just had to scout a (very) wide perimeter to find the baddies; this time, no such luck.

Comment: My edit was to change "mapped" to a more common term to (hopefully) make the language more clear to a wider audience. Feel absolutely free to roll it back if you don't find it beneficial.

Comment: Naw, I was just being lazy. Good edit.

Comment: A settlement defense should resolve itself without your involvement after a while. Your showing up may prevent this from happening, I suppose. did you try just waiting a few days?

Comment: Apparently, it was "less than ten times". See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Kill an Offender Within the Build Zone.**

In my case at Graygarden, the baddie spawned outside the buildable area and was killed on the spot.

Using `moveto [BadguyID#]`, brought the corpse to my location (standing inside the *town proper*). Then I used `resurrect` and in short order the quest was complete.

I did however have a corpse to work with in the first place. If there really never *was* anyone there, I'd *assume* you could spawn the right BadguyID to achieve the same effect. Mine was a 'Synth' settler; it may need to be a raider or a mutant, e.g.

Also note, that my resurrecting and "killing" 10+ guys (outside the construction area) may or may not have had any effect on the outcome.

**Edit:** It happened again; this time at Red Rocket. "Killing" ten guys seems to be key: I looted them every time I did it, ending up with 10 Synth parts.

**Tenth time's the charm.**

Comment: Yes, it was ten times! Thank you, I stopped using that trick after a few times because it felt wrong getting all the loot for free.

Comment: I am going to try this 10 time resurrect thing and see if it works.  I have a synth infiltrator that wouldn't let me finish the quest and I have been researching how to fix it for a while now.

Comment: I just had this issue and based on this solution, I resurrected the same corpse twice and then it completed the quest.

Comment: Make it stop : [Settlement Attacks Improved](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/26998/?tab=description)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to move baddies inside the buildable zone and resurrect it using the console command.  Particularly, there was a legendary baddy that seemed to trigger the quest complete.